# Suggested improvement on the FAQ — Link to Programmers.SE on the 'What topics' page

Tags: discussion, help-center

I know there are plenty of questions around the split between Programmers & StackOverflow (although tbh, I still don't think it's black-and-white), but just wanted to ask if the FAQ can be updated with a link off there.

At the moment, on the page *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*, we have this down the bottom:

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow, it
>   may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If your question
>   would be of interest to …
>
> - Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on Super User.
> - Professional system and network administrators, ask on Server Fault.
> - Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange.
> - Database administrators and professionals, ask on Database Administrators Stack Exchange.
> - SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on SharePoint Stack Exchange.
>
> If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may
>   commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack
>   Exchange communities are democratically created.

It feels like the site that SO overlaps most with is the one that should be listed most prominently, but it's not included at all.

Comment: Are you at all aware of the history of Programmers? It was initially NPR (Not Programming Related) and ended up as a dumping ground for anything and everything that [so] didn't want. It took a long time and much effort for it to come into its own. Most migrations to [programmers.se] ended up being **bad**, and it is unlikely this has changed - so, making it more visible on [so] is actually not something to [programmers.se] benefit.

Comment: Oh, and for some reason, you seem to have missed the _What topics can I ask about here_ section from [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (for comparison). Though there is some overlap, the scopes are very different.

Comment: @Oled Actually, I didn't miss it — I read both Stack Overflow and Programmers pages in full before posting. Your argument seems to be that people post on/migrate to Programmers because they're not informed of its real purpose & you want to address that by providing users with less information rather than more? That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: I was addressing the reason that Programmers is not included. It has most overlap, sure, but it also ended up getting all the rubbish that SO didn't want. And you know what? They asked to not get it anymore.

Comment: So you're saying that it's been excluded deliberately? Has the 'rubbish' gone down since they've been removed? It feels like they'd get less off-topics posts if they used the opportunity of people reading the FAQs in the network, to highlight to them what *is* on-topic for Programmers; ignoring the confusion does little to educate users.